# reference xml schema to xml file. explain

Tags: xml

I wrote xml schema for my xml file. and I am using xmllint linux tool to validate it.
I use the command : "xmllint --schema schema.xsd file.xml" I read in xsd tutorial that I can reference xml file to it's schema. how can this help me? how can I use this reference?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a schema from within the XML file using the noNamespaceSchemaLocation or SchemaLocation attribute. This tells the parser where to find a schema that can be used to validate the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML Studio 2012 Developer Edition 10.0.1.3941 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MySchema.xsd">
    <order>
    </order>
</Orders>
```